# Rename an XML node using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to rename a node in XML using PHP?

I Have come this far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;

// load the xml file
$dom->loadXML( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<library>
  <data>
    <invite>
      <username>jmansa</username>
      <userid>1</userid>
    </invite>
    <update>1</update>
  </data>
</library>', LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//find all 'data' nodes.
$node = $xpath->query("//data");

// if found
if( $node->length ) {
    foreach ($node as $n) {
       // RENAME HERE? //
    }
}

echo "<xmp>". $dom->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
```

Now, I want to rename `<data>` to `<invites>`. Can this be done and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

A Node's name ("data" or "invites" respectively) cannot be renamed via the DOM because the [Node::nodeName property is read-only](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).

You can create a new node named "invites", append it before the "data" node, move the children of "data" to the new "invites" node, remove the "data" node, and then output the tree to get your result.

**Example:**

```
<?php
// Create a test document.
    $dom = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

// Load the xml file.
    $dom->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?'.'>
    <library>
      <data attr1="1" attr2="2">
        <invite>
          <username>jmansa</username>
          <userid>1</userid>
        </invite>
        <update>1</update>
      </data>
    </library>', LIBXML_NOBLANKS );
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // Convert <data> to <invites>.
    if ($dataNode = $xpath->query("/library/data")->item(0))
    {
    // Create the <invites> node.
        $invitesNode = $dom->createElement('invites');
        $dataAttrs   = $dataNode->attributes;
        foreach ($dataAttrs as $dataAttr)
        {   $invitesNode->setAttributeNodeNS($dataAttr->cloneNode());   }
        $dom->documentElement->appendChild($invitesNode);

    // Move the <data> children over.
        if ($childNodes = $xpath->query("/library/data/*"))
        {
            foreach ($childNodes as $childNode)
            {   $invitesNode->appendChild($childNode);  }
        }

    // Remove <data>.
        $dataNode->parentNode->removeChild($dataNode);
    }

// Test the result.
    echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Wow... That sounds like a bit of work... Can't str_replace be used in some way?

Comment: It's not that bad. I'll edit my post with an example. I wouldn't advise using `str_replace` unless you are absolutely certain `<data>` and later `</data>` will only exist in that specific context (rare).

Comment: Ok, allthough I'm pretty sure it will allways be as in example. Looking forward to your example :-)

Comment: Example added. Notice that I really only added three sections after starting with your code. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: It works allmnost perfect!? If there is no <data> field it adds an <invites>?

Comment: It did, but I just updated the code so it will only add <invites> if <data> exists.

Comment: This solution does *not* preserve attributes when the element is renamed.

Comment: @feklee The OP example didn't have attributes, so I overlooked that in my answer. I have updated it to handle attributes as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, with extended test case:

```
// Changes the name of element $element to $newName.
function renameElement($element, $newName) {
  $newElement = $element->ownerDocument->createElement($newName);
  $parentElement = $element->parentNode;
  $parentElement->insertBefore($newElement, $element);

  $childNodes = $element->childNodes;
  while ($childNodes->length > 0) {
    $newElement->appendChild($childNodes->item(0));
  }

  $attributes = $element->attributes;
  while ($attributes->length > 0) {
    $attribute = $attributes->item(0);
    if (!is_null($attribute->namespaceURI)) {
      $newElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/',
                                  'xmlns:'.$attribute->prefix,
                                  $attribute->namespaceURI);
    }
    $newElement->setAttributeNode($attribute);
  }

  $parentElement->removeChild($element);
}

function prettyPrint($d) {
  $d->formatOutput = true;
  echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($d->saveXML()).'</pre>';
}

$d = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
$d->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
  <data a:foo="1" x="bar" xmlns:a="http://example.com/a">
    <invite>
      <username>jmansa</username>
      <userid>1</userid>
    </invite>
    <update>1</update>
  </data>
</library>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$elements = $xpath->query('/library/data');
if ($elements->length == 1) {
  $element = $elements->item(0);
  renameElement($element, 'invites');
}

prettyPrint($d);
```

By the way, I added this solution as a [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#111494) to the PHP documentation for `DOMElement`.