# PHP DOM: How to move element into default namespace?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces

What I tried and what doesn't work:

- Input:

  ```
  $d = new DOMDocument();
  $d->formatOutput = true;

  // Out of my control:
  $someEl = $d->createElementNS('http://example.com/a', 'a:some');

  // Under my control:
  $envelopeEl = $d->createElementNS('http://example.com/default',
                                    'envelope');
  $d->appendChild($envelopeEl);
  $envelopeEl->appendChild($someEl);

  echo $d->saveXML();

  $someEl->prefix = null;
  echo $d->saveXML();
  ```
- Output is invalid XML after substitution:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <envelope xmlns="http://example.com/default">
    <a:some xmlns:a="http://example.com/a"/>
  </envelope>
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <envelope xmlns="http://example.com/default">
    <:some xmlns:a="http://example.com/a" xmlns:="http://example.com/a"/>
  </envelope>
  ```

Note that `<a:some>` may have children. One solution would be
to create a new `<some>`, and copy all children from `<a:some>` to `<some>`. Is
that the way to go?

Comment: It is easier if you use a converter xml to array and backwards [example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexml

Comment: @AURIGADL Easier for the CPU or for the programmer? :)

Comment: I just realized that changing the namespace of a node (here: from `a` to default) is *the same as renaming* the node. So this question can be marked as a duplicate of the question ["Rename an XML node using PHP"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463550/rename-an-xml-node-using-php), which already has a decent answer.

Comment: I now found a robust solution which may be worthy an answer, despite the fact that moving to default namespace is akin to renaming.

Comment: The aforementioned solution is simply to create a wrapper for the [rename function from my answer to that other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15092434/282729): `function moveToDefaultNamespace($element) { renameElement($element, $element->localName); }`

Answer (score 3):

This is really an interesting question. My first intention was to clone the `<a:some>` node, remove the `xmlns:a` attribute, remove the `<a:some>` and insert the clone - `<a>`. But this will not work, as PHP does not allow to remove the xmlns:a attribute like any regular attribute.

After some struggling with DOM methods of PHP I started to google the problem. I found [this](http://www.php.net/manual/de/domnode.clonenode.php#90559) comment in the PHP documentation on this. The user suggest to write a function that clones the node manually without it's namespace:

```
<?php

/**
 * This function is based on a comment to the PHP documentation.
 * See: http://www.php.net/manual/de/domnode.clonenode.php#90559
 */
function cloneNode($node, $doc){
  $unprefixedName = preg_replace('/.*:/', '', $node->nodeName);
  $nd = $doc->createElement($unprefixedName);

  foreach ($node->attributes as $value)
    $nd->setAttribute($value->nodeName, $value->value);

  if (!$node->childNodes)
    return $nd;

  foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
    if($child->nodeName == "#text")
      $nd->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($child->nodeValue));
    else
      $nd->appendChild(cloneNode($child, $doc));
  }

  return $nd;
}
```

Using it would lead to a code like this:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<envelope xmlns="http://example.com/default">
  <a:some xmlns:a="http://example.com/a"/>
</envelope>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.com/a', 'some');
$original = $elements->item(0);

$clone = cloneNode($original, $doc);
$doc->documentElement->replaceChild($clone, $original);

$doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited your code a little bit, mainly fixed syntax, and added the `cloneNode` definition from the comment that you linked to. In the end this is actually what I proposed in my question *(copy all children)*, but of course it's nice to have a ready-made function.

Comment: Fine. I just didn't wanted to reproduce the code from the comment and also wanted to keep the code as short as possible

Comment: Had to tweak the function somewhat. I noticed, it doesn't remove the namespace prefix, i.e. in the original form it preserves `<a:some>`, while I want plain `<some>`.

Comment: Please don't edit too much. My answer - as is - worked as you expected. I have tested it

Comment: I've tested it too: There were syntax errors. Please don't understand me wrong: Your answer is great! Still I will wait a little bit before marking it as accepted.

Comment: Fine. ;) Then there must be a copy and paste error. I've just posted the working example. What syntax errors have you encountered?

Comment: For example: `Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::replaceChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given` I fixed that.

Comment: That's odd.. But however, if you are happy with the result I'll be too. :)

Comment: Please revert back to my last edit. That was the code that worked, and it included the necessary edit to `cloneNode` to remove the prefix. As it stands, I cannot mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24979/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-feklee)

Comment: No need for that. The code that I have (and that I edited in some minutes ago) works fine with PHP 5.3.

Comment: It was because you originally had: `$doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.com/a', 'some')->item(0)`

Comment: I finally got you ;) You should consider to add the edited function to the PHP documentation as a comment as well

Comment: `cloneNode` does not properly deep-copy elements, and the function is unnecessarily complex: The check `!$node->childNodes` is unnecessary. A robust solution should be to create a wrapper for the `renameElement` function found in [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15092434/282729): `function moveToDefaultNamespace($element) { renameElement($element, $element->localName); }`